# Is it possible without using parallelization (Swifter, Parallel) to make an instant calculation immediately without passing through the index?

Tags: pandas, indexing, aggregate, apply

Is it possible without using parallelization (Swifter, Parallel) to make an instant calculation immediately without passing through the index, for example through the use of the "apply"-function for all dataset?

```
%%time
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':random.sample(range(200), 200)})

for j in range(200):
    for i in df.index:
        df.loc[i,'A_last_{}'.format(j)] = df.loc[(df.index < i) & (df.index >= i - j),'A'].mean()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%%time
import random
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':random.sample(range(200), 200)})
```

First calculate the sums.

```
df[1] = df['A'].shift()
for j in range(2, 200):
    df[j] = df[j-1].fillna(0) + df['A'].shift(j)
```

Then do the division for means and take care of the formatting

```
df = df.set_index('A')
df.divide(df.columns, axis=1)\
    .fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)\
    .rename(lambda x: f'A_last_{x}', axis=1)\
    .reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! how i can customize code for other aggregation: std,max,min, median,sum?

Comment: If you don't divide, you get the sum. For min/max, you may change `df[j] = df[j-1].fillna(0) + df['A'].shift(j)` into `df[j] = df.assign(x=df['A'].shift(j))[[j-1, 'x']].min(axis=1)` and again don't divide. For std, if you have the mean, try follow the same logic to get variance first. For median, this logic won't apply.